# scp to NAS permission denied

Tags: samba, nas, scp

There are several ways to go, and I wish to find out about them.
I have a file on our ad server. I have root access for the server, and wish to copy over a file to our ad NAS.
The file is owned by a different user on the ad server with `-rw-r--r--`.
I have no problem to scp the file to my own node's `/home/user`.

I assume there are different ways to copy to the NAS. I tried with mounting the NAS both to my `/mnt` and `/media` folder.
I ran `scp centosminpuppet64-64.box user@ip:/media/iso` and ended up with permission denied. This was a try to copy it to my agent with the NAS mounted as:

> sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/nicox/.smb
>   //10.101.0.2/Groups/ /media/iso/

When NAS is mounted agents, `/media/iso` are, permissions of the NAS are:

> drwxr-xr-x 0 root root

Is there a way to workaround this, by changing permissions and ownerships?

I have an own user and password for our `Samba` NAS itself.
All our nodes are on the 10.101.x.x network.

This is how the NAS is set:

```
10.101.0.2/Groups
10.101.0.2/Users/my_user
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the exact permissions of the target directories on the NAS. The `scp` command should work as long as `user` has access to `ip:/media/iso`. However, it's not clear to me what `ip` is (the NAS presumably?) nor where `/media/iso` is. I'm guessing the NAS again but since you mentioned your local `/media` directory, it's really confusing.

Comment: I updated my question, hope it clears up your questions. I have access to `/media/iso`, the NAS is mounted on my own node. I can scp the file to my `/home/user` folder without permission denies. Our NAS is on 10.101.0.2/.

Answer (score 0):

OK, your issue is that you are mounting the NAS locally in a directory owned by `root` to which regular users have no access:

```
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root
```

To allow everybody to write to that directory, you need to run

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/iso
```

You should probably also mount the NAS with the `users` option:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/nicox/.smb,users //10.101.0.155/Groups/ /media/iso/
```

Comment: Just a correction for 10.101.0.155, it should be 10.101.0.2. I updated that before you probably noticed it. BTW what does the `users` option do, and should I use it for `Groups` or only `Users`?

Comment: @nicoX see `man mount`, the `users` allows anybody to mount or unmount the drive. It's probably not needed, just try changing the permissions on the mount point and mounting again. The simplest approach though would be to use `scp` and just make sure that `user` has the right to write to the NAS's directory.

Comment: The issue is when I mount the NAS to `/media/iso` it changes back the permissions to what the NAS regulates. I can't change the permission after the mount either.

Comment: As root user I can create files in the mounted NAS folder on my host.

Comment: @nicoX yes, but you are using `scp user@host` and not `scp root@host` so you're not connecting as `root`.

Comment: Correct. I don't have a root user account on my own host.

Comment: @nicoX you need to give the user you are connecting with write access to the target directory.

Comment: And this can only be done on the NAS server itself I presume?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14678/discussion-between-terdon-and-nicox).